# Logging structure - How to structure when every single method has to be logged?

Tags: c#, logging, design-patterns, postsharp, fody

I am having an issue with how bloated our logging looks.

We are logging every single method in a structure like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
  public class MyClass
  {
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public MyClass(ILogger logger)
    {
      _logger = logger;
    }

    public string AppendString(string originalText, string addedText)
    {
      using (new Tracer(_logger).TraceMethod(
        "MyNameSpace.MyClass.MyMethod()",
        () => new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
          {"originalText", originalText},
          {"addedText", addedText}
        }))
      {
        _logger.WriteInformation("Some extra info");
        return originalText + addedText;
      }
    }
  }

  public class Tracer : IDisposable
  {
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private string _methodName;

    public Tracer(ILogger logger)
    {
      _logger = logger;
    }

    public Tracer TraceMethod(string methodName, Func<IDictionary<string, object>> arguments)
    {
      _logger.WriteVerbose($"Entering method {methodName} with arguments {arguments}");
      _methodName = methodName;
      return this;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
      _logger.WriteVerbose($"Exiting method {_methodName}");
    }
  }
}
```

So we want to log:

- entry of method - ALWAYS
- exit of method - ALWAYS
- extra info - When appropriate

But, as you can see, this tiny little logic for merging 2 strings together becomes super bloated. It's very frustrating to see this kind of bloat in every single method.

We have looked into Aspects in frameworks like Fody and Postsharp. With these frameworks we would be able to add a [LogMethod] attribute on all methods and this would automatically add logging OnMethodEntry and OnMethodExit. This looks interesting but we still would have some issues.

1. How could we, on a method to method basis, log the parameters we feel appropriate? This will vary, and we certainly don't want to log all input parameters because it could be something like a huge xml. We also want to log these parameters in the same log message as the "OnMethodEntry" log.
2. We would still need to have an ILogger instance as a method injection. The instanziation of ILogger added a session ID. This sessionId that has been set at an earlier point is important. Would there be any way to solve ILogger in a different way? If we don't send in an ILogger to the constructor, how would we be able to log inside the method with the same instance of ILogger?

Comment: This is not an answer but a suggestion. Why reinvent the wheel? Can't you use one of those existing loggers such as [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) ? It's free and super easy to use.

Answer (score 3):

PostSharp Diagnostics addresses these scenarioes in the following way:

1. "Intelligent" formatting of parameters:

   a. You can implement a [custom formatter](http://doc.postsharp.net/custom-formatter) and include the logic you want. However, the formatter will only receive the parameter value, not the parameter metadata.

   b. If your formatting logic needs to depend on the parameter metadata (e.g. you define a *custom* custom attribute), you can implement what we call a [custom logging back-end](http://doc.postsharp.net/custom-logging-backend) and you will override the [SetParameter method](http://doc.postsharp.net/m_postsharp_patterns_diagnostics_recordbuilders_logrecordbuilder_setparameter__1_fbe352ce).
2. Consuming the injected ILogger:

   a. I don't really advise to inject the logger as a dependency. Although it is orthodox, it is unpractical for use with an aspect-oriented solution. PostSharp Diagnostics creates one ILogger per type under the hood, not for each instance.

   b. If you choose not to inject ILogger, PostSharp Diagnostics allows you to easily mix automatic log records and [manual log records](http://doc.postsharp.net/manual-logging). The manual records will be displayed in the right context.

   c. That said, you can create a  [custom logging back-end](http://doc.postsharp.net/custom-logging-backend) (or adapter) that will consume your instance-level ILogger. You will need to expose your logger to an interface, say ILoggable. Then your custom adapter can consume ILoggable.ILogger. There is no difficulty in that.  However, it does not combine well with 2.b, because manual log records emitted using our framework carry no information about the `this` instance (as of PostSharp 5.0). But instead of logging custom records using the PostSharp's Logger class, you will be able to use your own ILogger.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the [Decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern where you create a `LoggingMyClass` that contains just the logging code and then delegates to the real `MyClass` to do the work. This is a neat pattern but, depending on how many classes you need to decorate, the volume of code can grow quickly. However, it will allow you the customised logging that you need.

An alternative that minimises the amount of code is interception using something like Castle's [DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/). This isn't such an accessible technique and might not give you the customisation that you seek. It's worth investigation though.

> If we don't send in an ILogger to the constructor, how would we be able to log inside the method with the same instance of ILogger?

You could consider using an [AmbientContext](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ploeh/2007/07/23/ambient-context/) for the logger. However, I've noticed in the latest [book](https://www.manning.com/books/dependency-injection-in-dot-net-second-edition), this pattern has fallen out of favour.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of a solution to use aspects plus custom annotation to specify the parameters you want to log if any and reflection to process the annotation. I didn't get completelly your second issue but it sounds to me that it's more appropriate to handle it somehow inside the annotation processor.